# How to know if a number is positive or negative or 0

Tags: c, if-statement

Is it possible to know if a number is `positive` or `negative` or `0` in `c language` using only two `if conditions`?

If yes, then how? please let me know

Comment: Are you serious? What did you try?

Comment: Yes I am, I tried with terinary operator, switch case also, but every where it is taking 3 conditions

Comment: What are the three conditions???

Comment: You need 2 comparisons.  1: Negative or not. 2: (if not negative, 0 or negative)

Comment: Yuo do know about "if .. else" ?

Comment: @devnull No, that's not a duplicate...

Comment: @Lundin I was prompted to mark it a duplicate after looking at an answer that seemed like a _verbatim copy-paste_ from my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @devnull The question isn't a duplicate, only the answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because only escapees from the lunatic asylum would ever do such a thing. SO is supposed to be about real problems that you face, not arbitrarily limited things that no-one would ever encounter :-)

Comment: @user2753523 if you have tried something show us that, if you ask question like you will get down votes so better edit your question and show us what you have tried.

Comment: In any case, the following fits your description: `if (x < 0) {puts ("-ve");} else {if (x > 0) {puts ("+ve");} else {puts ("zero");}}

Answer (score 3):

Use only two `if`s:

```
if (num <= 0) {
      if (num == 0) {
          /* num is zero */
      } else {
          /* num is negative */
      }
} else {
    /* num is positive */
}
```

Comment: Mmm.. if `num` is zero, your code would first say that it's zero, then say it's negative, and then positive.  Isn't it?

Comment: are you sure you r not missing else?

Comment: @devnull You are right, `else`s are missed.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this can solve your problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float num;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f",&num);    // Take input from user
    if (num<=0)          // if Number is >= 0
    {                    
        if (num==0)      // if number is equal to zero
          printf("You entered zero.");
        else             // if number is > 0
          printf("%.2f is negative.",num);
    }
    else                // if number is < 0
      printf("%.2f is positive.",num);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `c` is a floating point, the problem becomes interesting.

`c` may be
1) > 0
2) < 0
3) = 0
4) "Not-a-Number"

```
#include <math.h>
...
int classification = fpclassify(x); 
if (classification == FP_NAN || classification == FP_ZERO)) {
  if (classification == FP_NAN) puts("NaN")
  else puts("zero");
}
else  {
  if (signbit(x)) puts("< 0" )
  else puts("> 0");
}
```

At most, 2 `if()`s executed.

Without using classification functions/macros

```
if (x != x || x == 0.0)) {
  if (x != x) puts("NaN")
  else puts("zero");
}
else  {
  if (x < 0.0) puts("< 0" )
  else puts("> 0");
}
```